# Boolean Parenthesization Problem's code is not working

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Regarding the "Boolean Parenthesization" problem, my code doesn't work. I tried the approach using the dynamic approach, however for the the input of `N=5` and `T^F|F`, I got `0` as the output but the correct output is `2`.

I ran the following test cases:

##### For Input:

```
5
T^F|F
```

##### Your Output:

```
0
```

##### Expected Output:

```
2
```

I tried the following code:

```
class Solution {
    static int countWays(int N, String S) {
        int dp[][][] = new int[N][N][2];
        int mod = (int) 1e9;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (S.charAt(i) == 'T') {
                dp[i][i][1] = 1;
                dp[i][i][0] = 0;
            } else if (S.charAt(i) == 'F') {
                dp[i][i][1] = 0;
                dp[i][i][0] = 1;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                for (int isTrue = 0; isTrue < 2; isTrue++) {
                    int ways = 0;

                    if (i > j)
                        continue;   
                    
                    for (int k = i+1; k < j; k += 2) {
                        int lt = dp[i][k-1][1];
                        int lf = dp[i][k-1][0];
                        int rt = dp[k+1][j][1];
                        int rf = dp[k+1][j][0];
                        
                        if (S.charAt(i) == '&') {
                            if (isTrue == 1) {
                                ways = (ways + lt*rt) % mod;
                            } else
                                ways = (ways + lt*rf + lf*rf + lf*rt) % mod;
                        } else if (S.charAt(i) == '|') {
                            if (isTrue == 1)
                                ways = (ways + lt*rt + lt*rf + lf*rt) % mod;
                            else
                                ways = (ways + lf*rf) % mod;
                        } else {
                            if (isTrue == 1)
                                ways = (ways + lt*rf + lf*rt) % mod;
                            else
                                ways = (ways + lt*rt + lf*rf) % mod;
                        }
                    }

                    dp[i][j][isTrue] = ways;
                }
            }
        }

        return dp[0][N-1][1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs:

- `if(S.charAt(i)=='&')` is testing the wrong character. You want to test the character at the index `k`, not `i`. Same with the second comparison with `'|'`.
- `if(i>j) continue;` will allow the iteration to progress normally when `i` and `j` are equal, but that means that the inner loop with `k` will not run and that at the end of it, `dp[i][j][isTrue] = ways;` will always set `dp[i][j][0]` and `dp[i][j][1]` to zero, wiping out what you had put there in the initialisation part. So now all `dp` values will be zero before continuing with the accumulation of values. This will be fixed by doing `if(i>=j) continue;`

With those two fixes it will work. But still:

- It is a waste of time to have `j` iterate with values greater than (or equal to) `i`. Just start have it immediately start at a valid value, `i+2`.
- Have the loops on `i` and `j` increment with steps of 2, as the other indexes are irrelevant.
- Calculate the number of ways for false and true at the same moment, instead of looping with `isTrue`.

Here is adapted code:

```
    static int countWays(int N, String S) {
        int dp[][][] = new int[N][N][2];
        int mod = (int) 1e9;  // NB: on GeeksforGeeks this should be 1003

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 2) {
            dp[i][i][1] = S.charAt(i) == 'T' ? 1 : 0;
            dp[i][i][0] = 1 - dp[i][i][1];
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j += 2) {
            for (int i = j - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
                int waysTrue = 0;
                int waysTotal = 0; 
                for (int k = i + 1; k < j; k += 2) {
                    int lt = dp[i][k-1][1];
                    int lf = dp[i][k-1][0];
                    int rt = dp[k+1][j][1];
                    int rf = dp[k+1][j][0];
                    int ff = (lf * rf) % mod;
                    int ft = (lf * rt) % mod;
                    int tf = (lt * rf) % mod;
                    int tt = (lt * rt) % mod;
                    char ch = S.charAt(k);
                    waysTotal += ff + ft + tf + tt;
                    waysTrue += ch == '&' ? tt
                              : ch == '|' ? ft + tf + tt
                              : ch == '^' ? ft + tf;
                }
                dp[i][j][1] = waysTrue % mod;
                dp[i][j][0] = (waysTotal - waysTrue) % mod;
            }
        }
        return dp[0][N-1][1];
    }
```